# Como ler mais de um registro com READ TABLE?

Tags: tabela-banco-de-dados, erp, abap

É possível fazer um `READ TABLE` no ABAP para ler mais que uma linha?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

Não tem como fazer diretamente, tem que usar uma laço. Exemplo da [documentação](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abapread_table.htm):

```
DATA itab TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF i
          WITH EMPTY KEY
          WITH NON-UNIQUE SORTED KEY sort_key COMPONENTS table_line.

itab = VALUE #( ( 2 ) ( 5 ) ( 1 ) ( 3 ) ( 4 ) ).

DATA(output) = ``.
DATA(idx) = lines( itab ).
WHILE idx > 0.
  READ TABLE itab INDEX idx USING KEY sort_key
             ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs>).
  idx = idx  - 1.
  CHECK <fs> > 2.
  output = output && <fs> && ` `.
ENDWHILE.

cl_demo_output=>display( output ).
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/xBase/ABAPReadTable.abap).

Answer (score 0):

Read Table e feito para selecionar apenas 1 linha de uma tabela transparente. Você precisa usar um loop para selecionar o conteúdo desejada de uma tabela para outra.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá @Igor. Evite colocar imagens de código. Edita a sua resposta e coloque lá o código estruturado ao invés da imagem.

Answer (score 0):

Como os amigos já mencionaram anteriormente, a expressão READ TABLE na linguagem ABAP não passa de um SELECT SINGLE, se formos trocar por miúdos...

Onde SEMPRE trará apenas UM registro a cada vez que seja processado, a grande diferença entre SELECT SINGLE  e READ TABLE é que no primeiro, a busca dos dados é feita no banco de dados e o segundo é feito pela tabela interna (apenas em tempo de execução ), Tendo isto como base. se você precisa "Juntar" duas tabelas por exemplo, é muito simples...

Vamos supor que você tenha a necessidade de exibir em um relatório os dados de Código de Material (MARA-MATNR), Data de Criação (MARA-ERSDA) e por fim a DESCRIÇÃO de material(MAKT-MAKTX) neste caso, precisamos unir duas tabelas, para completas as informações que necessitamos para a exibição:

O código ficaria basicamente assim:

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF y_saida_relatorio,
      matnr TYPE mara-matnr,
      ersda TYPE mara-ersda,
      maktx TYPE makt-maktx,
   END OF y_saida_relatorio.
DATA: w_saida_relatorio TYPE y_saida_relatorio,
      t_saida_relatorio TYPE TABLE OF y_saida_relatorio.
* Selecionando dados do banco de dados
SELECT matnr,
       ersda
  FROM mara
INTO TABLE @DATA(t_mara).
IF sy-subrc IS INITIAL.
SELECT matnr,
spras,
maktx
FROM makt
INTO TABLE @DATA(t_makt)
FOR ALL ENTRIES IN @t_mara
WHERE matnr EQ @t_mara-matnr
AND spras EQ 'PT'.
IF NOT sy-subrc IS INITIAL.
FREE t_makt[].
ENDIF.
ENDIF.
* Selecionando dados da minha tabela interna (Existente somente em tempo de processamento)
SORT: t_mara BY matnr,
t_makt BY matnr spras.
LOOP AT t_mara
INTO DATA(w_mara).
* Buscando 1 informação por vez na tabela interna
READ TABLE t_makt INTO DATA(w_makt) WITH KEY matnr = w_mara-matnr
                                                  BINARY SEARCH.
IF sy-subrc IS INITIAL.
w_saida_relatorio-matnr = w_mara-matnr.
w_saida_relatorio-ersda = w_mara-ersda.
w_saida_relatorio-maktx = w_makt-maktx.
APPEND w_saida_relatorio TO t_saida_relatorio.
CLEAR w_saida_relatorio.
ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.
```